# How i can optimize this code, whithout creating variable `a`?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, vue.js

Help to optimize below functions, whithout creating variable `a`

```
getFieldsGroups(){
  let a = [];

  if(this.activeTab.fieldsGroupName === ''){
    this.activeTab = {
      groupIndex: 0,
      subgroupIndex: 0,
      fieldsGroupName: this.groups[0][0].name
    }
  }

  this.groups.forEach((group, groupIndex) => {
    group.forEach((fieldsGroup, fieldsGroupIndex) => {
      if(
        groupIndex == this.activeTab.groupIndex &&
        fieldsGroup.name == this.activeTab.fieldsGroupName
      ){
        a.push(fieldsGroup);
      }
    })
  })
  return a.length == 1 ? [] : a;
}
```

```
getFields(){
  let a;
  
  this.groups.forEach((group, groupIndex) => {
    group.forEach((fieldsGroup, fieldsGroupIndex) => {
      if(
        groupIndex == this.activeTab.groupIndex &&
        fieldsGroup.name == this.activeTab.fieldsGroupName
      ){
        if(this.activeFieldsGroup.name === '' && fieldsGroup.name === this.activeTab.fieldsGroupName){
          a = group.filter(_fieldsGroup => _fieldsGroup.name === this.activeTab.fieldsGroupName)[0];
        }else if(fieldsGroup.label == this.activeFieldsGroup.label){
          a = fieldsGroup;
        }
      }
    })
  })

  return a.fields.length == 1 ? [] : a.fields;
},
```

Comment: If you tell is what you try to establish it would get more helpful responses.

Comment: `map`, `filter`. Possibly `reduce` or `flat`, since it looks that nested arrays need to be unwrapped. No `forEach`.